# Residual fat: can all fat be dealt with?

Tags: fat

Is there such a thing as residual fat? That means, fat that will stay there in your belly, thighs or other place? Does your body save fat just for emergencies?

It might sound as a silly question, but this is a pretty demotivating thought of mine when dieting or doing physical exercise. I always think that I won't manage to have a flat belly, no matter how hard I try. Maybe my body only lets me reduce my fat up to x% before getting sick and leaves my belly fat untouched.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Given the focus on reducing body fat in fitness, knowing what the minimum for good health is is important.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - I didn't downvote, but I did vote to close, as I regard it as being off topic. It's a question about fat, unrelated to exercise except for the words "physical exercise" in the second paragraph (Which is not a question). The basic questions are "Is there such a thing as residual fat" and "Does your body save fat for emergencies", neither of which have anything to do with exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your body does [require a minimum amount of body fat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipose_tissue) to survive and function properly and has roles beyond simple calorie storage. In fact, your brain has a small amount of adipose tissue that is necessary for brain function. So it is impossible to have a body fat percentage of 0 and survive.

I would focus on a healthy diet and exercise plan that helped reduce your body fat to a healthy level. If you are concerned about how you will look in the future, investigate resistance training to increase your muscle mass. Often when people speak of "[toned bodies](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/how-can-i-get-more-toned)" its just a low ration of body fat to muscle mass.

If you are concerned about losing fat particularly off your stomach, unfortunately, where our fat deposits are located is entirely genetic. [Spot reduction is a myth unfortunately](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Myths.html). Focus on a healthy diet, with resistance training and you will feel healthier and look better.