# Cardio or gym machines for best fat burning?

Tags: weight-loss

So I made a contract with a gym to lose fat and become fit. My goal is something like this [image]

Now I'm over weight so I need to lose fat (I think something like 14KG). I told the trainer in the gym about my goals and that I don't want big muscles or so. So the program he gave to me is to do exercises with some weight machines in the gym:

1- a machine that trains the legs muscles.

2- another the trains the back, and chest.

3- then an exercise with TRX for my stomach.

& that was it. Then I was so confused that he didn't assign me any cardio exercises like running machine or cycling! His argument was that when I train my muscles, then the body needs to burn fat and that's how the fat will be burned. But then I insisted to go on the running machine and then he asked me to run one minute fast and then one minute slow. I found that I had a lot of sweat with the running machine than with the weight machines!

The trainer said that I should do many repetitions with low weights on the machines and that's how I achieve my goal.

My question is:

1- Is the trainer correct? Is it better to use the weight machines for fat burning than with cardio machines?

I'm worried because I don't want big muscles! I want to be fit and lose fat quickly! I don't want to work hard and then find out that it's not the bodyshape that I want.

Comment: [This already has an answer here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/how-can-i-get-more-toned) and it has the exact same example picture!

Comment: NOOOO it's not the same!!! I'm asking if the program in the gym is correct for me or not!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr this is my first time in gyms and I read that link you posted many times but couldn't figure out if my program/routine is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving any kind of goal includes hard work. Doing a lot of reps with low weights is exactly what you have to do to be 'toned' not over muscly. If you feel like running is good for you no one will hold you not to do it. However saying that you planning on loosing about 14kg you should really considering your diet. You can loose a lot of weight by speeding up your metabolism. Try to drink a lot of water and eat quick digestible foods.

Comment: Downvote for this sentence: "Doing a lot of reps with low weights is exactly what you have to do to be 'toned' not over muscly." This is an unfortunately common misconception, and I wish you wouldn't perpetuate it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman why is wrong?!!!!

Comment: @JohnKugelman and if it's wrong, then what is the correct thing?! :O