# Exercises to Tighten My Body During Weight Loss?

Tags: weight-loss, skin

I'm 25 years old and 173cm height. I was fat almost all my life until the age of 23 when I decided to lose fat. At that time I was 88 KG. Then in 6 months I lost until I became 72KGs. What I did was just diet with walking for 2 hours. However at that time I wasn't happy with the result of my body because I still saw ugly loose skin. But then my studies started and I got so busy with it. Because of stress I gained fat, so now I'm 77KGs. So I decided to go to the gym now and do one hour of cardio. I do intensive running on the machine for 1 hour (I run at 10K/h for 1.5 minute, and 0.5 minute walking at 5.5/K/h). I burn with this hour 600 calories. Of course I'm controlling my diet now. Not the same difficult diet that I did in the past, but I only reduced my food intake a little and cut sweets and sugar completely. I guess I eat around 2000 calories per day.

When I started training at the gym I was 78KG, now I'm 77KG after 1.5 week.

However I'm really concerned about the excessive/loose skin that I might get since my plan is to loose weight until I become 65 KGs. After that my plan is to start lifting weights to get a *toned fit* body (I [read this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/how-can-i-get-more-toned) so I'm aware of it, but this is my goal). My biggest concern now is the loose skin. Can you please recommend for me excercises/machines to use to help me tighten my skin?

I need to note that in the gym we have those vibrating machines. A guy told me that these help to tighten the skin, so what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there are no exercises for skin tightening but you can use products such as coconut oil, aloe vera and other such topical products to regain elasticity in the epidermis.

That being said, proper hydration, good eating habits in terms of nutrients and avoidance of direct sunlight will help to maintain your collagen levels high so that the skin will respond quicker to the weight loss.

In the worse case scenario, there are cosmetic surgery procedures to remove excess skin due to rapid weight loss.

My recommendation is take the long road.  Remember that it took you a while to get to the weight you have...  losing it in a healthy way should take a while too.  Thought thankfully, not as long as it took you to get there.