# How to tone without losing or gaining weight

Tags: exercise, diet, toning

In the past 2 years I have managed to lose about 75 lbs.

It was a slow process as I am not as dedicated as should have been.

**Unique** Right now I am at the size I want to be, however I'm "flabby" I guess you could say.

I really dont want to loose anymore weight and also do not want to gain.

Talking to a couple friends both of which I do not think have ever weight problems are telling me I either need to:

Build muscle, protein drinks, weight lifting and lots of cardio

Tone muscle, Low cardio, light weight more reps weight lifting.

I think I want to Tone the muscle I have and possibly Build muscle where I lack.

Are they both right or is there a better way?

Also diet is important, is there foods that are better for what im trying to do.

**Unique** Also to help in my googling, does what Im trying to do have a name?

There is really nothing in the suggest duplicate that asks the main apart of my questions.

This question is geared toward people who have lost weight and have excess skin they are trying to tighten, find a question that is a duplicate of that and I will think about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get more "toned"?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13502/how-can-i-get-more-toned)

Comment: If you have "excess skin", no amount of dieting will help especially if the skin has been stretched beyond its normal capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congrats on the weight loss! That is quite an accomplishment.

There is, absolutely no such thing as "toning muscle" in the sense that people seem to think. There's building muscle and losing fat. Think of it as putting a tarp over a pile of objects. The tarp is your skin, the air under the tarp is fat, and the objects being covered is muscle.  You put more stuff under the tarp, the tarp gets bigger. You push air out, the tarp looks less rounded, and you start to see the shapes of the objects being covered. Same thing happens with body composition.

What you seem to be looking for is called [recomposition](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=recomposition) in which you lose fat and gain muscle at the same time. Doing so keeps your weight somewhat stable (you may gain or lose weight but not at extreme rates).

It's hard to do recomposition as it takes a carefully balanced diet with the appropriate macro-nutrients (protein, carbs, fat). It also gets harder to do as you progress over time. You build less muscle as you get to your genetic max, and you burn less fat as you get leaner.

There are many ways to recomp. I'm sure you can find a hundred different suggestions, but the two consistent factors are a good solid diet and a physically intense training regiment.

A good diet would require you to first figure out what your macro nutrients are. There are a lot of [online calculators](https://www.iifym.com/iifym-calculator/) that help. General guidelines are first you figure out what your *maintenance calories* are. These are the calories you eat at where you won't gain or lose weight. Allocate calories 0.8 - 1 gram of protein per pound of lean body mass, 0.5-0.8 grams of fat per pound, and whatever's left in carbs.

Then you need to find a decent weightlifting program. Preferably full body workouts which would include things like squat and deadlift. Lift heavy and in good form. That means low-reps, high weight. Basically if you've done 8 full reps of something than the weight is too light and you should increase it. Practice [progressive overload](https://bretcontreras.com/progressive-overload/) which basically means do slightly more than the previous time.

Comment: Nice metaphor, i'll steal that.