# Whether or not to buy weighted vest

Tags: strength-training

I'm looking into buying a weighted chest vest (probably adjustable 140 lbs in 2.5 increments) and adustable ankle and wrist weights. I do alot of walking and moving around at work but I'm not wanting to build muscle would wearing these three in combination help tone and build up longer lasting muscle and help tighten up tendons and muscles instead of bulking up?

Comment: You say that you don't want to build muscle and that you do want to build muscle.  Which do you want?

Comment: Regarding "toned" https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13504/7091

Answer (score 3):

Response to training is very specific.
Walking around with a Weight Vest is obviously a greater stress than your own bodyweight but it will do very little to improve your strength. Plus, if your strength increases it will be for activities close to the ones you do with the vest so I suppose mainly static or slow movements. There would be nearly no transfer towards actual activities which usually require to move and/or a greater speed of execution.

To strengthen your ligaments, eccentric training as well as plyometric (take care if you have never done any plyometric work, it can be quite stressful)

Answer (score 0):

Weighted vest should ideally be used to add resistance to pull ups or push ups. I would not recommend buying one just to wear when walking around due to the pressure added on joints over time. You'd be better off doing body weight exercises like push ups/pull ups/air squats to shape up if you're not able to go to the gym.