# Why I am not losing weight?

Tags: exercise, jogging, treadmill

I started rigorous exercise for last one week only - 30 minutes treadmill jog burning around 260 calories + 10 minutes of cycling burning around 30-40 calories.

However despite that, my weight is not reducing. I am also drinking lot of water (1 liter) and having subway in both meals.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong - thanks.

Comment: Lol....you do realize you need to burn at least 3500 calories to lose one pound? And it's just one week.

Comment: There is quite a bit of debate on the 3500 calories recently, but I agree that the OP needs more time and attention to diet.

Comment: Wait, SUBWAY? Be careful with that. http://www.subway.com/nutrition/nutritionlist.aspx

Comment: What is a good alternative to Subway? I tried salads but didn't really like them and also started feeling hungry again soon after having them.

Comment: Add that as another question or look through other posts. Lots of diet/nutritional questions on site

Comment: related: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily/13256#13256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ali, 
 
your current exercise routine goes:

- 30 mins treadmill jogging - 260 calories
- 10 mins cycling - 40 calories
- Subway both times - daily lunch/dinner from Subway *(correct me if the assumption is wrong)*

#### Questions:

- Apart from Subway meals, do you consume any other snacks or meals?
- Did you perform your exercises everyday?
- What's your current weight? Above 200 lbs?
- What's your weight-loss goal *(how many lbs do you desire to lose)*?
- Male or female?

Your exercise level isn't high enough to give you the results you desire. According to your exercise log, you burn only 300 calories daily from your exercises. *That's less than the calories from one meal at Subway!* If you continue this particular plan, it'll take a while for you to lose the weight *(from exercise alone)*. 
 
If you don't snack and the above are the only food intake you have, you should begin to see results very soon *(although you should switch from Subway to something more healthy)*. 
 
To take your exercise level more seriously, extend the time spent on cycling *(to at least 30 minutes)*. If possible, switch from jogging to sprinting and jogging and do it at least 45 minutes. Doing these daily *(or frequently)* should allow you to see more result. 
 
However, if you need to lose more than 50 pounds and you're getting impatient *(don't worry, you're not the only impatient one)*, you'll have to increase your exercise level *(again)*. You might need to add body-weight exercises as well as weightlifting. There are many recommendations but I don't need to bother you with them at the moment. 
 
Also, ensure you aren't starving yourself. You can't lose weight by going hungry all the time. Cut calories intake without being unnecessarily hungry. 
 
BTW, don't forget to join some fitness community too; it would be easier for you to lose weight in the community. 
 
Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, Subway is the only meal I have.

Answers to Questions:
1. Apart from Subway meals, do you consume any other snacks or meals? No
2. Did you perform your exercises everyday? Yes
3. What's your current weight? Above 200 lbs? 170 lbs
4. What's your weight-loss goal (how many lbs do you desire to lose)? 15 lbs
Male or female? Male

So if I understood correctly, you are suggesting to (a) increase jog+sprint to 45 minutes and (b) cycling to 30 minutes. Correct? Please suggest if I need to add any other exercise routine or work out plan to shed weight soon.

Comment: Do you have other options? Subway might not be one of your best choices.

Comment: Also would appreciate if you suggest a healthy alternative to Subway. I tried salads but don't really liked them and felt starved soon after having them.

Comment: For nutrition, you might want to eat fruits/nuts daily. Some fruits help more than others. Apples, almonds, pistachios are great snack examples. For meals, cap each meal at about 400/450 calories and make it more than twice *(depending on your schedule)* . Ensure you aren't always hungry. Salads are good choices too *(you can add grilled chicken and lots of nuts to it to fill you up)* . Greek yogurt and cheese are good snack too. You don't want to be skinny; so, I'd recommend body weight exercises too. Do at least 10 pushups and 5 pullups daily. Increase the reps you get stronger.

Comment: Perform 30 seconds plank/bridge frequently *(awesome if daily)* to build your core. Reverse crunches, standing crunches will help your core and lower abs too. If you want to start weightlifting, try deadlifting and squatting. Also, try to stay informed as much as possible and tweak these information to make them work for you. Become a lean, mean version of yourself :).

Comment: Thanks so much for quick response and valuable ideas. I will definitely add them in my workout/diet.

One more question - how much calories should I target to burn in daily workout?

Comment: As many as you can. Don't focus on the calories burned; focus on the intensity of the exercises and the awesomeness you see in yourself. Focus on the proper forms when exercising and enjoy your workout. Try to make as much fun as you can; the transformation will amaze you. Also, don't wait till workout time to exercise. Try to include them in your daily routine: pushup/pullup after waking up, jogging/sprinting to your office, planks/crunches before bedtime, pushup when you're bored. Mix and match :). Make it fun and glorious :)

Comment: Great answer and advices. Thanks a lot. Wish me luck :)

Comment: Thank you. *Tip: Always ensure you don't go two days in a row without working out. If you ever feel  like not working out for a long time, check out Youtube videos of people working out; the motivation will naturally return*. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an active lifestyle, you need to start with knowing how many calories you need to maintain your weight.  The easiest way to do that is to maintain a food diary.  Record everything you eat and drink.  The simple act of recording your caloric intake will remove all guess work.  Once you've established how many calories you need to maintain, simply cut back (while maintaining the same activity level, or, increased activity level) on your daily calories.  This method is not perfect, but, it is better than guessing at what to do.

I'd also watch my intake of "Subway" as others have noted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be dis-heartened,  you may have started to tone, and may of actually started to lose inches, so you should take measurements as well as using the scales.

I often find that clients have lost no weight, yet they have lost 2 inches around their waist.

As per previous comments, a week is a very short time to see a difference.  When you exercise more your body requires more calories just to maintain weight.  Therefore, if you exercise more and eat the same you will loose weight.

Good luck with your journey