# Fitness schedule to get in good shape, 27, overweight

Tags: getting-in-shape

I am a 27 yo, I am overweight(175cm for 98kg) and right now practicing little to no sports (biking everyday for 40 mins and an occasional swim in the pool).

When I was younger I practiced swimming and capoeira, enjoying both higly, but abandoned sports due to time constraints and lazyness.

I am now in a moment of my life where I have some spare mental energy and time (and I also recently gained quite a bit due to unehealty eating habits and no exercise) to devote to getting fit.

One of the main issue is that until I am fit I have a hard time making myself do exercises. I could, e.g. , go to the swimming pool, but without a clear set of exercises to perform I would get out of the pool feeling like I have not exercised satisfactorily.

I ask you to provide an exercise plan keeping in mind the following:

- **Free body** : any exercise should be carried out without using any instruments, I don't mind push ups or similar, but I don't like lifting weights or having to go to specific places to carry out the routine.
- **Scalable** : ideally, the plan is composed of a sequence of exercises to perform any other day. Starting with a low number of repetitions which can be approximately multiplied up after a period of time (e.g. 10 push-ups the first two weeks, than 1.5x each week until the seventh week). *Bonus*, if it could be split into smaller sessions (e.g. two 30 mins sessions) to fit other scheduling issues on occasion, great!
- **Detailed** : I wish to take as few decisions as possible on what I should do during a training session, so please make a specific list (10 of this, 20 of that, take a break, 10 of that other one). Include the needed stretching exercises and resources with descriptions of the exercises.
- **Space requirements** : ideally, (most) of the exercises are  doable at home, or in the park, or in an big enough area in the office.
- **Goals** : the main goal is to lose weight and get fit and energetic, and keep exercising as an habit. The training session should be a moment of *HARD* work that challenges my current ability at any time and improves my fitness.
- **Likes and dislikes** *Bonus*, anything that could get me more flexible is welcome. I always enjoyed stuff like handstands and yoga-like stuff where you slowly assume different challenging positions. I do not like running at all.

This is what I ask for a complete answer, but please feel free to chime in with suggestion or resources, or even just part of routines that I could fit in. I will probably end up stitching pieces together for the final workout sheet, so all suggestions are welcome.

Thank you :)

**EDIT** [This is a related question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily) with useful information, but my request here is about building a set of exercise with some specific requirements.

Comment: I also would like to be 1.9m tall and a millionaire. Joking apart...  usually no amount of exercise will make you lose weight unless you control your diet. Check this close question http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am aware of that, I just wanted the question to be focused on getting a exercise schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fitness schedule to get in good shape?**

First off, I would like to say that is tons of information over the internet and this site itself when it comes to losing weights.

Let start off with your free body routines. Here are some routine that can be found over the internet or decent enough for overweights/newbies to begin with:-

[Baristi Beginners Workout](http://baristi-workout.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-calisthenics/)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or [incline pull ups/inverted rows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t97EjUsCFNw).

---> Can't do dips? Do bench dips (either with [foot on the floor](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDipFloor.html) or [on another bench](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWBenchDip.html)) or more close grip / normal push ups.

[Buff Dude's Punisher Prison BW Workout](http://www.buffdudes.us/blogs/news/25290561-punisher-prison-bodyweight-workout)

---> Can't do one arm push ups? Just do close grip / normal push ups

---> Can't do handstand press? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

---> Can't do L-Sits? Do [planks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSHjTRCQxIw) or [hanging leg raises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g1hxdkulsE), follow the set and seconds provided

[Fortress Beginners Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qEE3x27PE)

---> Can't do pull ups? Do a [negative pull ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f3wkcdmVN8) or incline pull ups

---> Can't do a pistol squat? Do your normal squats

---> Can't do handstand hold? Do [pike push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sposDXWEB0A)

P.S **Can't do regular push ups?** Do [knee push ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWPushupKnee.html) or [wall push ups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RtM3L00BUU).

Next, your diet:-

First off, calculate your [TDEE](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/) and **subtract 200~500 calories**(this is known caloric deficit). Next your protein intake should be **1g per lbs of bodyweight**, where as your fat intake should be around **0.5 ~ 0.6g per lbs of bodyweight** and the remaining can be used to fill up your carb intake, and your micronutrients(aka vitamins and minerals).

However, this is also highly debatable since there is no **right or wrong answers**. By that, what I mean is that you need to adjust your calorie(if necessary) to ensure you are losing weight.

**What about resting times?**

Generally, I would aim for 30 seconds to a minutes rest **depending on how I'm feeling**. I don't advocate following a routines' resting time as some may need more rest time than others.

Lastly, do note that it **takes time to either build muscle or lose fat**. Do not get disheartened when don't see any result in the next few days, weeks, months. Also, do you have any mobility issues? If so, do include in your original post.