# How to reduce belly and face fat

Tags: running, weight-loss, workout, bicycling, fat

I am 26 years old, M, 5'7 height. I have been doing exercise running- 30 mins daily and cycling - 20 mins. I do crunches also in my daily activities. I drink lot of watter like hell, not taking alcohol, taking less calories these days. I have stopped taking sugar also

I had almost 72kg weight 3 months back, I made it to 67kg now. I have still a fat on my face and stomach.

```
Food Structure :-

Start with breakfast - Sprouts, Poha
Lunch - 2 Chapati with Vegetable
Dinner - 2 Chapati with Vegetable
```

Can anyone suggest what exercise and daily practice should I  do to reduce face and belly fat.

Comment: Consider eating more meat.

Comment: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily  would help you .

Comment: Sounds like you just need to keep doing what you're doing - ~2kg weight loss per month is a decent rate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, **you can't target fatloss.**

You can however make some healthy changes to your life, most of which you've already done by the looks of it. Most people have a hard time losing fat on their abdominal area. The only thing you can do is keep living healthy, tracking caloric intake, making sure you get enough rest and working out regularly.

Things like ab workouts won't help you lose belly fat faster than doing cardio,the contrary is actually true. You'll lose faster doing cardio, high intensity interval (HIIT) or heavy compound lifts rather than doing isolation exercises like crunches.