# How to decrease Lower Belly after Delivery?

Tags: bellyfat

I am a mother of 45 day old baby. Even after delivery my lower belly still looks like I'm 7 months pregnant. Please give me a good suggestion to decrease my belly size. I am not talking about normal belly, its about delivered mother belly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are ab exercises more usefull to reduce belly fat than other exercises?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9581/are-ab-exercises-more-usefull-to-reduce-belly-fat-than-other-exercises)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Understanding the changes**

45 days is absolutely nothing to worry about. As a rule of thumb, six months is about the time it takes for your body to reverse the effect of a pregnancy. Remember, it took nine months for the changes to happen in the first place.

A lot of this is of course also subject to genetics. We're not all the same. Some women can regain their previous stature in a matter of weeks. Others take months. And months is the most common.

**Helping the process along**

There are lots of things you can do to help speed up the process of getting your figure back.

- Breastfeeding, because lactating can burn about 500 calories per day
- Five fruits/vegetables per day
- Maintain a fibre-rich diet (oats, beans, lentils, grains, seeds)
- Gentle exercise, particularly pelvic floor exercises
- Take walks! Of course, this is quality time with your child as well

**Tummy slack**

It's very common for tummies to feel slack after birth, because the added volume over-stretched it. You may see a bulge on the front of your tummy, above and below the belly button. This is known as Rectus Abdominis Diastatis (RAD) and is a divarication of your abdominal muscles.

If you believe you have this, you should go see a midwife or a doctor. Leaving it untreated isn't directly harmful, but it can lead to back problems later, and it will make it harder to have a flat stomach post-pregnancy.